# SQL - using datediff between two tables with join

Tags: sql, join, datediff

I have a scenario where I need to generate a report addressing the following requirement:

`Display status of each support ticket. For each ticket include number of updates, the problem, status, time elapsed between ticket being logged and first update, and the time between ticket being logged and final update.`

The database schema for relevant tables is:

```
Ticket (TicketID, Problem, Status, Priority, LoggedTime, CustomerID, ProductID)
TicketUpdate (TicketUpdateID, Message, UpdateTime, TicketID)
```

I have the following so far:

```
SELECT t.TicketID,
       COUNT(tu.TicketID) AS 'Number of Updates',
       t.Problem,
       t.Status,
       (
           SELECT DATEDIFF(HOUR, MIN(UpdateTime), MAX(UpdateTime))
           FROM TicketUpdate
           WHERE TicketID = t.TicketID
       ) AS 'Hours bw Q and Last response'
FROM Ticket t
    LEFT JOIN TicketUpdate tu
        ON t.TicketID = tu.TicketID
GROUP BY t.TicketID,
         t.Problem,
         t.Status;
```

Which doesn't address the requirement, but I was experimenting with the function. I was expecting I would be able to use alias inside the datediff function but apparently I can't (correct me if I'm wrong please).

Any help with this issue would be greatly apreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aggregate the updates first;

```
SELECT t.*, tu.NumUpdates,
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.LoggedTime, tu.FirstUpdateTime),
       DATEDIFF(HOUR, t.LoggedTime, tu.LastUpdateTime)
FROM Ticket t LEFT JOIN
     (SELECT tu.TicketID, COUNT(*) as NumUpdates,
             MIN(tu.UpdateTime) as firstUpdateTime,
             MAX(tu.UpdateTime) as lastUpdateTime
      FROM TicketUpdate tu
      GROUP BY tu.TicketID
     ) tu
     ON t.TicketID = tu.TicketID
```

Comment: if I may bother you for one more issue sorry. I seem to be running into problems running this query:
SELECT t.Priority, Count(t.TicketID), tu.MinUpdateTime, tu.MaxUpdateTime
FROM coursework.Ticket t
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT  tu.TicketID, 
MIN(tu.UpdateTime) as MinUpdateTime,
MAX(tu.UpdateTime) as MaxUpdateTime
FROM coursework.TicketUpdate tu) tu
ON t.TicketID = tu.TicketID
WHERE tu.TicketID IN (t.TicketID)
GROUP BY t.Priority;
I'm trying to get this:
For each priority, list how many tickets have been processed, and min time elapsed between ticket being logged and last update to ticket.

Comment: I'd be extremely grateful for any help @Gordon Linoff!

Comment: @MAK7 . . . Perhaps you should ask a new question with sample data and desired results.